# useState (setState) not setting array items as intended

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My goal is to take the information from **tempArr** and set it as **postData**. If I don't use the if statement it keeps looping through all the data from the before mentioned array. While the **tempArr** contains all the necessary information from DB, I think that the problem lies in the **useEffect** hook because as far as I understand it just doesn't loop through it the second time. Sadly I have no idea how to fix it.
A picture from console is provided to better understand the problem.

```
const [postData, setPost] = useState([])

const axios = require('axios');

let done = false;
let tempArr = []

useEffect(() => {
    axiosPull()
    console.log(done, "before the if statement")
    if(done){
        console.log("inside the IF statement")
        {setPost(tempArr)}
        done = false
    }
    
})

const axiosPull = () => {
    const url = 'http://localhost/.../api/product/bookRead'
    const url2 = 'http://localhost/.../api/product/furnitureRead'
    const url3 = 'http://localhost/.../api/product/dvdRead'

    axios.get(url).then(response => response.data)

    .then((data) => {
        data.data.map(data =>{
            tempArr.push(data)
        })
    })

    axios.get(url2).then(response => response.data)

    .then((data) => {
        data.data.map(data =>{
            tempArr.push(data)
        })
    })

    axios.get(url3).then(response => response.data)

    .then((data) => {
        data.data.map(data =>{
            tempArr.push(data)
        })
        console.log(tempArr)
        done = true
        console.log(done)
    })
};

return (
    <div>    
        <div className="productContainer">
            <Post posts={postData} />
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably have an empty dependency array in that `useEffect` to prevent it running on each render.

```
useEffect(() => {
  axiosPull();
}, []);
```

You can a) shorten your code, b) remove the dependence of a local component variable (`tmpArr`), and c) set state within the `axiosPull` function itself.

```
function axiosPull() {

  const url = 'http://localhost/.../api/product/bookRead'
  const url2 = 'http://localhost/.../api/product/furnitureRead'
  const url3 = 'http://localhost/.../api/product/dvdRead';
  
  // Group the urls in an array
  const urls = [url1, url2, url3];

  // Create an array of promises
  const promises = urls.map(url => {
    return axios.get(url);
  });

  // Wait til they either resolve/reject
  Promise.all(promises).then(responses => {

    // Then `map` over the responses of each
    // resolved promise and return the data you were
    // adding to `tempArr`. You may need `flatMap` here
    // instead of `map` depending on your use-case
    const mapped = responses.map(data => {
      return data.data;
    });

    // And then set the state with that data
    setPost(mapped);

  });

};
```

Comment: The problem now is that the program creates 3 posts which are 3 arrays. Even tho I map them in another class where I use them they stay as an array.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments try using `flatMap` instead of `map`.

Comment: I made it work with regular .map. And thanks for the answer.